# Given an llvm::AllocaInst, how do I get llvm.dbg.declares that refer to it?

Tags: llvm

I have an `llvm::AllocaInst` that I need to get the `llvm.dbg.declare` or `llvm.dbg.value` intrinsics that refer to it. None of those are present in the `alloca`'s `uses()` list.

```
AllocaInst *AI = ...;
for (Use const &U : AI->uses()) {
  dbgs() << *(U.getUser()) << "\n";
}
```

None of the debug uses of the allocation are printed out.

Comment: How are you checking the uses list? Are you looking for a CallInst to those functions?

Comment: I have checked the uses list, and I don't see them in it. Are they supposed to be?

Comment: I am not sure if they are supposed to be there or not. But I would assume that it should be there. I was curious about how do you check the list I your code.

Comment: One thing that you can do is go through every call to intrinsic that comes after ```AllocInst``` and check if it is using the value of ```AllocInst```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`FindAllocaDbgDeclare` function](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#aabf35a012f84ad0dab49cd5b7dec7965). You'll need to include `llvm/Transforms/Utils/Local.h`.